# Can a C# TPL dataflow propagate completion upstream?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

When linking dataflow blocks, you can choose a "propagate completion" setting. This essentially propagates the completion from a source to a target.

However, I have an application where data is being pulled from a database and a downstream block is watching for some condition to be true. When this condition is achieved, I want to kill the dataflow. Essentially, I want my downstream block to propagate completion upstream.

How would I do this using TPL data flow?

Comment: Maybe you should introduce side effect to your downstream block, so when condition is met it just generates something like 'Shutdown Event' that upstream block is listening to. In other words upstream block is notified that it should complete the dataflow pipeline/network.

Comment: @BART That's what I'm thinking of doing. Have the downstream hold a reference to the upstream block and then call the Complete method on it.

Comment: How abrupt do you want this completion to be? A CancellationToken will abort all blocks, discarding any buffered data

Answer (score 2):

The most safe and direct way of killing a dataflow is by passing a cancellation token to all blocks, and then cancelling the token. It's more direct than calling `Complete()` to the producer block, and then waiting for the last items to be processed.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var producer = new BufferBlock<X>(new DataflowBlockOptions()
{
    CancellationToken = cts.Token
});

// ...

cts.Cancel();
```

Comment: In my use case, the last dataflow block is what controls the cancellation. Would it be bad practice to pass the cancellation token source to the block itself?

Comment: @Izzo passing a `CancellationTokenSource` to a dataflow block is impossible. You can only pass a `CancellationToken`. You can pass the same `CancellationToken` to all blocks of a pipeline (this is my suggestion).

Comment: Because my last data flow block is responsible for flagging completion, and I can't give control to the cancellation token to a dataflow block, how would this method work?